# htaccess File need two RewriteRules

Tags: .htaccess

Ok so I have a site that needs to have 2 RewriteRules on it.

First if you go to newvendor.business.com it will go to newvendor.business.com/newform.php

Second I need it to go from newvendor.business.com/pending to newvendor.business.com/pending/index.php when you click on the link with that id. Here is the htaccess file that works for the first rule but not then pending one.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/?([a-zA-Z_+]+)?/?([0-9]+)?/? $1.php?action=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-p
RewriteRule ^pending/([0-9]*)$ /pending/index.php?id=$1
```

Can you do this or not? If so can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. the bit about newform.php:

1.a. [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)

```
DirectoryIndex newform.php index.php index.html
```

Pros:

- The URI actually stays "/" , and not "/newform.php".

Cons:

- Maybe you do want users to see "/newform.php"
- Beware having newform.php anywhere in sub folders - DirectoryIndex setting is inherited and you might end up with an unexpected result (though this is pretty far fetched scenario).

1.b. [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /newform.php
```

Pros:

- Precision - only this specific URI is being redirected (sub folders not affected).

Cons:

- None that i can think of at the moment

1.c. [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /newform.php [R,L]
```

Pros:

- emm.. using mod_rewrite to make me a sandwich?

Cons:

- Invoking mod_rewrite is not a very light operation, although irrelevant if you're going to use mod_rewrite for other rules...

## 2. The rest...

2.1. Using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^pending/([0-9]+)$ pending/index.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/?([a-zA-Z_+]+)?/?([0-9]+)?/? $1.php?action=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Basically, i changed rules order, since your "first" one was matching pending/[0-9]+$ as well and control never reached beyond that point.

2.2. Leveraging [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews)

Although this won't be a pure configuration-only solution (will require some changes in php files), this may let you avoid using mod_rewrite...

So, in order to do this, you need to enable `MultiViews` option:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Then you just construct a "pretty" URL like "/article/123/edit" and, if there's a file called *article.php*, it will be invoked, although you didn't mention the .php extension
Then, *article.php* file can grab `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` and parse it the way it sees fit...

As for the pending/* - it is possible to use `ErrorDocument` inside pending folder for this scenario

```
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
```

And then also check `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`

So, there you have it... both with and without mod_rewrite ;) The decision is yours ;)

Comment: P.S. What is **-p** in your last `RewriteCond` line? it does not exist in the [mod_rewrite manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot! The -p was a mistype so sorry for that.